# AJAX 500 (Internal Server)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to debug this AJAX script and but I can't see what the problem seems to be. Chrome developer tools is showing "500 (Internal Server Error), doWork @ (index):16 , onclick @ (index):28

Can someone explain to me what seems to be the problem with this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Get the HTTP Object
function getHTTPObject() {
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
    }
}
var httpObject = getHTTPObject();
function doWork() {
    if (httpObject.open != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET", "verify.php?account="
            +document.getElementById('account').value
            +"&pass="
            +document.getElementById('pass').value, true);
        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}

// Change the value of the outputText field
function setOutput() {
    if (httpObject.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
    }
}

</script>

<form action="">
Account:<br>
<input type="text" name="account" id="account" value="">
<br>
Pass:<br>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" value="">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Verify Account" onclick="doWork();">
<p id="outputText">&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Comment: A `500: Server Error` is well... a server error, it's an error in your backend code. The problem is in whatever's in `verify.php`.

Comment: You are doing a `GET` to `verify.php` You could start by trying to point your browser to the url that your ajax function is trying to fetch

Comment: `HTTP Error 500` is because of server fault, not client side fault. Check if you can access `verify.php?account=...` manually (without AJAX).

Comment: Chrome developer tools will also show you the **response body**.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message told you, not your Script, but your server side application is crashing on getting the request. In lack of further information, I couldn't tell you more.

Answer (score -2):

Some 500 Internal Server Error issues can be corrected by deleting the cookies associated with the site you're getting the error on.

After removing the cookie(s), restart the browser and try again.